# VS2010 remote debugging with default transport problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tcp, managed, remote-debugging

I need to do remote debugging of managed code (.NET) on a server hosted on a different network. Neither the client or server is on a domain so i have to use the public ip of the server.

I'm trying to use Visual Studio -> Attach to process -> default transport with the qualifier john@xx.xx.xx.xx but it's not working.

I get the error message : **"Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named 'john@xx.xx.xx.xx'. There is no server by the specified name running on the remote computer"**

This error message tells me i can connect just fine but it can't find the msvsmon instance (which is 'john@WEB-001'). So i tried to use the combination of qualifiers such as WEB-001\john@xx.xx.xx.xx and xx.xx.xx.xx\john@WEB-001 but neither are working.

If I choose the transport "Remote (Native only with no authentication)" it connects just fine and I can see the process list on the server but it is pretty much useless because I can't debug managed code.

The administrator 'john' exists on both computer with the same password

**Windows 2008 R2 X64 (Server)**
Remote debugging component (VS2010) X64 installed
Firewall off
Msvsmon new server named 'john@WEB-001' running as john

**Windows 7 X64 (Client)**
Visual studio 2010 running as john
Firewall off

Any idea how to fix this, or is this scenario not supported? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

having you tried putting web-001 in your hosts file, and connecting as john@web-001?

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work.

"Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named 'john@WEB-001'. There is no server by the specified name running on the remote computer"

Weird.

Comment: Maybe enable auditing on both ends and watch your security eventlog for fails and successes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the server name to your hosts file:

```
192.168.1.100 WEB-001
```

Replace the IP with your own. Native code debugging is done over plain TCP/IP with no security but native code requires DCOM to enforce security, I don't understand the reason but ....

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread now but.

When the remote debugger is first installed you can set a firewall setting that allows all web traffic or only subnet connections. Run the configuration again to allow all web traffic.

Also, as the Administrator account, not a user in the Administrator group, Shift+r-click on the debugger shortcut to execute as a different user. Enter in the other user account that has the same username and password as the machine you are debugging with, in this case john.

This is the process I have to use.